# How to update model B when modification of model A happens?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm developing with django an application for the management of the company budget.
I noticed that with django to be able to modify the data contained in my db I always have to go through a required view. But, once I have entered data through a form, I would like to make changes to the dataset. Is it possible?

I'll give you an example:

through my form I collect the data of the monthly collections per business unit:

```
                  | ____ Jan ____ | ___ Feb _____ |

Business unit_1 | ____ 100 ___ | _____ 100 ____ |

Business unit_2 | ____ 100 ____ | ____ 100 ____ |
```

I'd like to populate another model at once with totals per month from the data shown above:

```
      | ____ Jan ____ | ___ Feb _____ |
total | ____ 200 ____ | ____ 200 ____ |
```

And I want that, if I delete a row in business unit, automatically the total is udpdated.

Do you think I can do it directly in the view and so utilziing only django? if yes how? or do you recommend another way ?

Comment: By the `second db` do you mean a model, a query or a separate database?

Comment: the second db is a model in which have 12 instance, one for each month, equal to the total sum of each month

Comment: You can use signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend keeping it within the view.  Once the form saves, get the appropriate model (Total) and update the value (Month) accordingly.  You could also use signals and there's a good tutorial on it at https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Hope this helps!